# Does every linear integer polynomial give a square at some integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, quadratic-residues

My question is, if you have some function
$$f(x)=nx+c$$
which accepts only integer inputs of $x$, where $n>0$ and $c$ are fixed integer constants, can you always find an $x$ such that
$$f(x)=k^2$$
where $k$ is an integer, i.e. the result is a perfect square.

Comment: Plenty of counterexamples with non-integer $n$ and/or $c$.

Comment: Sorry fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: all squares are equal to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$, so $n=3$, $c=2$ is a counterexample. Indeed, you can probably find infinitely many such, since the same is true modulo $4$, and probably for larger moduli.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $y$ is a perfect square then $y\equiv0,1\pmod4$:

- $z\equiv0\pmod4 \implies z^2\equiv 0^2\equiv0\pmod4$
- $z\equiv1\pmod4 \implies z^2\equiv 1^2\equiv1\pmod4$
- $z\equiv2\pmod4 \implies z^2\equiv 2^2\equiv0\pmod4$
- $z\equiv3\pmod4 \implies z^2\equiv 3^2\equiv1\pmod4$

Therefore:

If $n\equiv0\pmod4$ and $c\equiv2,3\pmod4$ then $nx+c\equiv2,3\pmod4$ hence not a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has already been answered, I would like to put my two cents with certain cases for which the answer is positive.

We are considering $n$ integer and $c$ positive integer. If
$$
f(x)=nx+c=k^2,
$$
then
$$
x=\frac{k^2-c}{n}
$$
Now, assume **$c$ is a perfect square**. Then,
$$
x=\frac{(k+\sqrt{c})(k-\sqrt{c})}{n},
$$
and the answer is positive, as we can observe by taking $k=n-\sqrt{c}$:
$$
x=\frac{(n-\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c})(n-\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{c})}{n} = \frac{n(n-2\sqrt{c})}{n}=n-2\sqrt{c}.
$$
For the sake of completeness, you can check this with $n=70$, $c=25$, which yields $k=65$ and $x=60$.

Comment: You don't need $c$ to be a square.  $y=x+2$ yields a square when $x=7$, for example.  We were asked about every polynomial, not some polynomials.

Comment: I know you do not need $c$ to be a perfect square, and you probably can find infinitely many examples where $c$ is not a perfect square but the answer is positive. I just made an effort to find **sufficient** conditions that make the answer true.

Answer (score 0):

All depend of the constants $(c,n)$. You need that $x^2-c\equiv0\space (mod\space n)$ in order to have solution. For example, for $(c,n)=(3,7)$ you have no solution and for $(c,n)=(4,7)$ you have.